# Alternative for Toast plugin

Tags: android, cordova, toast

I have a android application built using cordova 2.9.0. I am trying to add a gmail style alert (having no buttons and disappearing after some time). I tried using toast but I am not able to get it to work. Can It be because I am using older version of cordova and latest toast plugin?

Are there any other plugins like toast which can help me display a alert with a timer?

Comment: cordova 2.9.0 is really old. Could you try switching to another version?

Comment: cordova 2.9.0 apps won't be approved on the play store, you should update

Answer (score 0):

if this is plugin you use http://plugreg.com/plugin/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin, that it is supported on cordova 3.0 and higher.
Could you post name of your plugin?

Comment: In documentation is says that plugin works with cordova 3.0. You have to update your cordova

Comment: There is no other way I can get older version of the plugin which is compatible with cordova 2.9.0

Comment: You can try to follow this [link](http://teusink.blogspot.in/2013/04/phonegap-android-toast-plugin.html) but I would rather suggest switching to newer version of cordova.

Comment: Thanks. I will switch to new version